# Excel : How to restrict maximum number of users to an shared excel file in our organisation's server

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have shared excel workbook on my organisational file server. I created this for online attendance system for my org. We have around 20 sections. One tab (excel sheet) is dedicated to each section with username and password.

Then I created usernames for each section of my org. When he logs into the workbook, the sheet dedicated to his section is visble to him, rest all sheets are hidden for him.

And my request is... Is it possible to restrict only one user at a time for one excel sheet (only one can login at a time into one section's attendance system, even if another one of same section logs into it, he should get a warning saying that so & so user is already editing that parrucular sheet).

And further how can I restrict maximum number of persons editing the workbook to 5 or 10.??

Comment: Are you wanting to permit multiple users to open the Excel workbook simultaneously, but only allow one user at a time to have write access to a particular worksheet? (Note that your use of the terms "sub section" and "tab" is unclear. These are not standard Excel terms.)

Comment: Sub section is a smaller part of my organisation. For such section, i have made one excel sheet(tab) to enter the attendance and created username & password. Now I want to only one person at a time to login into a particular tab (basically tab dedicated to the section he belongs)... If another person tries to login into same tab, he should get a warning saying that so & so user is already editing that particular sheet. Further, i want to restrict total number of persons to 5 or 10 to edit the workbook at a time.

Comment: how are you handling the logon process for each worksheet? Through VBA? Or password-protection of individual worksheets?

Comment: With particular username, only one excel sheet mapped to that username is visible and rest all are hidden through vba.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all this information. Ping me when done so I can retract my close vote.

Comment: I edited the question...